# Why is my YouTube video not showing up?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am simply trying to have a YouTube video show up on my site, but instead I'm getting a blank shape of the video. Does anyone know why this could be or how to fix it? Thanks. Here is the portion of my code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="345" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIsCs9_-LP8">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?  Did you try multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple browsers. It doesn't show up regardless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key issue is the `Youtube URL` is missing the `embed` part.  Every `Youtube` video has a `embedded` option.

You have:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIsCs9_-LP8
```

However we need to remove `watch?v=` and add `embed/`:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/nIsCs9_-LP8
```

The first link is meant for the Youtube site (not just the video, but the whole site) itself.  The second is a version for the video itself which is what you need to *embed* onto your site.

Try this (straight from the Youtube video's embed option):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nIsCs9_-LP8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: No problem.  If you thought this answer was helpful/correct, a checkmark and upvote would be most gracious.  |=^]